# C++ tree with multiple children for telephone number inverse search

Tags: c++, search, tree, children, inverse

I'm trying to write a program to do an inverse search of telephone numbers (user gives a number and program prints out the corresponding person + other numbers that belong to it). Now I have saved the persons' datas in a linked list and am trying to bild up a tree.

Each tree element will save a pointer to a person's data, an index (which is corresponding to a part of the telephone number, for example if the number starts with '0' the index of the root's first child node is '0') and a vector of pointers to it's children.

What I can do so far is saving the first given number in the Tree but there seem to be problems when trying to save more than one number in the tree. Maybe the problem is with the pointers to the children nodes, but i'm not sure there. Here's the said part of the code:

```
class Tree {

public:

    Datensatz *data; //data stored in node
    char number; //index of node - part of a telephone number
    Tree* wurzel; //root

    vector<Tree*> nextEls; //vector of children of node


    Tree(int zahl);


    /*
     div. functions
    */

    void add(vector<char>); //called to add telephone number to tree

};



void Tree::hinzufRek(vector<char> telNum)
    {   
    Tree *aktEl = new Tree(); //latest node
    aktEl=this->wurzel; //starts with root

    int check = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<telNum(); i++) { 

    char h = telNum(i);

    if(aktEl->nextEls.size()!=0){
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j<aktEl->nextEls.size(); j++) {         
            if (h == aktEl->nextEls[j]->number) { //if latest number already exists in node children...
                aktEl = aktEl->nextEls[j];
                check = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (check == 0) {
            aktEl->nextEls.push_back(new Tree(h));
            aktEl = aktEl->nextEls[j];
        }
    }
    else { //if there are no current children to latest node
        aktEl->nextEls.push_back(new Tree(h));
        aktEl = aktEl->nextEls[0];
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Furthermore, I thought it would be a good idea to delete the Tree* aktEl object at the end of the function, but that only leads to really strange results. I'm not sure if the above code is very clear or if it can be easily understood, but I hope one of you can help me...

Maybe I'm just overseeing something...

Thank you in advance!

roboneko42

Comment: Unless your current implementation is required (e.g., as part of homework) just use an `std::map<phonenumber, person_data>`.

Comment: Agree with Jerry here, std::map<> will simplify your task much more. If I not mistaken, the std::map<> stores data in a tree structure as well, alowing speedy access to your data.

Comment: The data structure you are poorly emulating is called a `trie`.  No, that isn't a misspelling.  As for deleting, use `unique_ptr`.